# Keras Sequential Model: fit_generator with batch input

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, sparse-matrix

I have been trying to train a Sequential Keras model using a sparse matrix. Although I have specified the batch size in the code, it is being trained at batch_size = 1 (i.e. one row at a time).

Here's the code:

```
def batch_generator(X_toGen, y_toGen = None, batch_size = 32):
    counter = 0
    sample_index = np.arange(X_toGen.shape[0])
    np.random.shuffle(sample_index)
    while True:
        batch_index = sample_index[batch_size*counter:min(batch_size*(counter+1), X_toGen.shape[0])]
        counter += 1
        X_batch = X_toGen[batch_index,:]
        if y_toGen is not None:
            y_batch = y_toGen[batch_index]
            yield X_batch.toarray(), y_batch
        else:
            yield X_batch.toarray()
```

Can anyone please help me in generating a batch input for the Sequential model? Also, how different would the accuracy be when the model is being trained at batch_size = 32, rather than batch_size = 1?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are getting is not 1 batch size output from this generator. Let me give you an example here:

If you have total 1000 samples and you are dividing this in batches 10. Then using fit_generator you will get only 10 batches which means you have 10 batches each of 10 samples.

So, the crux is fit_generator shows number of batches instead of total number of samples.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, the variable batch_size would specify the number of batches into which the total input is divided (example, if there are 1280 rows of input, then batch_size = 32 would create 32 batches of 40 samples each)?

Comment: No, it would create 40 batches of 32 samples each.

Comment: Each batch will have samples equal to the batch size.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's working like that. When I'm calling the fit_generator function, the UI indicates that each of the rows are parsed individually to the function, and not by the batch size specified.

Comment: What is your total sample size and how many steps each epoch is taking?

Comment: I ran an initial input of approximately 1500 rows with a batch size of 32. The UI showed the same number of steps as input (1500) and was moving through each step individually.

I ran this for a smaller sample for 30 rows with a batch_size of 5 and the results were the same. It moved through 30 steps individually

Comment: Have you also specified steps_per_epoch=1500/32? Else it will show you NaN after sometime.

Comment: So that was the issue! I was under the impression that the steps_per_epoch was to indicate the number of rows that should be parsed for training

Comment: Okay. So in steps_per_epoch you need to mention number of batches which in your case are 1500/batch_size.

Comment: Done! But it won't change the displayed score as my reputation is still too low for that :p. Also, do you know how the batch_size would affect the accuracy for an ANN?

Comment: Yes, batch_size is one of the hyperparameters. Try different combinations and see what gets you the best results.